# How to send a form in GET and keep current url parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form select in blade file.

```
<form action="{{ Request::url() }}" method="get">
  <select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
</form>
```

I need that when sending my form, the old parameters of the URL remain.
I've url like that :

`http://example.com/about-us?request=2d`

But if I send my form, I've a URL like this :

`http://example.com/about-us?year=2017`

And I would like that

`http://example.com/about-us?request=2d&year=2017`

How can I do this in my blade file?

Thank you

Comment: Add a hidden input to pass that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can add hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="request" value="{{ request('request') }}">
```